# Problem with responsive CSSGrid and hover

Tags: css, css-grid

i use CSSGrid with an hover effect who works great on desktop, but i have a bug on mobile and can't find the problem.

You can see the page here, and look on desktop on mobile view: http://lafabutineuse.flywheelsites.com/realisations

I defined my image title and link to be absolute and 100% height of the div.

The code of my title on image:

```
 h2 a, h2 {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px!important;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition-property: background;
    -webkit-transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

and same code on hover but with differents colors:

```
h2 a:hover, h2:hover {
    background: rgba(224,197,76,0.61);
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    align-items: center!important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px!important;
    text-align: center!important;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

I tried some codes to fix the problem but can't achieve to keep the same effect on mobile.

Do you have any idea please?

Thank you

Comment: Also have a read here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not explicitly set `position` for `.et_pb_grid_item` on screens smaller then 980px - that's why your hover-link takes 100% of `.et_pb_portfolio_items`.
Set `position: relative;` for `.et_pb_grid_item` and that should fix the hover problem.

```
.et_pb_grid_item {
    position: relative;
}
```